# How do I update my my accessibility registry without needing a reboot?

Tags: windows, windows-10, powershell, windows-registry, accessibility

I am currently modifying some values in the Mousekeys registry under `HKCU:\Control Panel\Accessibility` using PowerShell.

How can I have my changes take effect without a necessary reboot?

If I go into the ease of access center and modify the mousekeys configurations, all I need to do is hit the 'Apply' button for my changes to take effect.

What is going on behind the scenes when the 'Apply' button is clicked?

I have tried restarting `explorer.exe`but that has not worked.

Comment: "How can I have my changes take effect without a necessary reboot?" - You don't have to reboot you just have to logout of the current user.  There is no way around the requirement of either logging out of the user or rebooting.

Comment: Like @Ramhound said - if its gotta be done, its gotta be done...

Comment: What happens when you hit "Apply" is undocumented and without source code access it would be very difficult to determine this. But knowing probably wouldn't help you anyway. It likely involves things you can only duplicate by logging out or rebooting. Programs can do a great many things you can't do directly.